# Devise reset password mail in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for authenticating user, role based authentication done using the boolean attribute in user model (admin), Admin devise routes are separated using subdomain admin. While implementing forgot password feature   reset_password_instructions mail, always be in admin subdomain and, the path "admins/passwords" is being set, how @resource always set as admin?,

how can I implement forgot password mailer for two different roles?

Comment: do you have multiple devise models?

Comment: No single devise model with multiple roles(boolean column to determine whether the user is admin or not)

Comment: Does the boolean value has a default?

Comment: Yes . the default value is false